# Using MDX_Sum (MTD) for current and previous month

Tags: mdx

I have this script to retrieve Sum of MTD for current and previous month, I have hard coded this, but I want something dynamic like Getdate in SQL.

My scripts:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LeadsCurrentMTD] AS 
        Sum
        (
            MTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20210318]),
            [Measures].[Lead Count]
        ) 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LeadsPreviousMTD] AS 
        Sum
        (
            MTD([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20210218]),
            [Measures].[Lead Count]
        ) 
SELECT 
    {
        [Measures].[LeadsCurrentMTD],
        [Measures].[LeadsPreviousMTD]
    } ON 0
FROM [EDW];
```

Comment: this code is not written in DAX, this is MDX

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StrToMember` function in `MDX` alongside the *vba* function `NOW()`

[image]

So in your `WITH` clause you'll have sort of constructs to make things dynamic:

```
STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[" 
+ cstr(datepart("yyyy",now()))
+ cstr(datepart("mm",now())) 
+ cstr(datepart("dd",now())) 
+ "]")
```

Comment: @Melvin glad it helped - dynamic dates inside MDX are not very pretty!